# SSI/mod_include: new ap_expr syntax not working as documented

Tags: apache, ssi, mod-include

My website uses SSI (server-side includes) to check a condition (using `#if expr`) and return different HTML code based on whether the condition is true or false.  This used to work fine for years until recently, my website started showing the error `[an error occurred while processing this directive]`.  I found out that [the `expr` syntax changed in newer versions of Apache httpd](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html#flowctrl), so I assume that my hosting provider upgraded the Apache httpd recently and that caused the old syntax to break.  The Apache httpd is now at version 2.4.29.

I managed to fix the problem temporarily by adding `SSILegacyExprParser on` to my `.htaccess` file to go back to the old syntax (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48751195/5824489)).  But I would like to find a permanent solution using the new syntax.

Here is the old syntax SSI code that works with `SSILegacyExprParser on`:

```
<!--#if expr="${thisDoc} = /impressum\.shtml/" -->
<li id="current">
<!--#else -->
<li>
<!--#endif -->
```

(The variable `thisDoc` has been set earlier.)

Here is the SSI code using the new `ap_expr` syntax that doesn't work.  It shows `[an error occurred while processing this directive]` again.  I was following the documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html when writing this code:

```
<!--#if expr="%{thisDoc} =~ /impressum\.shtml/" -->
<li id="current">
<!--#else -->
<li>
<!--#endif -->
```

I've tried modifying the syntax in various ways, for example to avoid using regex matching and use exact string comparison instead, but that didn't work either.  I couldn't get a single expression to work in the new syntax.

Why is the new syntax not working?

Answer (score 1):

I found that I needed to use the `env` function to access environment variables in more recent versions of httpd (without the `SSILegacyExprParser` flag set.)

So `${thisDoc}` becomes `env('thisDoc')` or `env("thisDoc")`.

Tested as working with Apache httpd 2.4.56 on Fedora 37:

```
<!--#set var="thisDoc" value="home.shtml" -->
```

and then somewhere afterwards:

```
<!--#if expr="env('thisDoc') =~ /impressum\.shtml/" -->
<li id="current">
<!--#else -->
<li>
<!--#endif -->
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I unfortunately can't test whether it fixes my problem because I no longer have access to the server where it originally happened. But I still appreciate your effort!